# Error checking in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

A small question about code cleanliness in angular reactive forms ...
In our forms, we often get fragments like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"
     *ngIf="formGroup.controls.openDateGroup.controls.preOpenDate.errors?.noFutureDateViolation; let errorInfo">
    Pre open ({{errorInfo.value | febDate}}) date is not in the future
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger"
     *ngIf="formGroup.controls.openDateGroup.errors?.preOpenBeforeOpenViolation; let errorInfo">
    Pre-open date ({{errorInfo.openDate | febDate}}) may not be after open date ({{errorInfo.preOpenDate | febDate}})
</div>
```

Is there a way to make this fragment cleaner? The reactive forms directives (formGroupName and formControlName) know on which level they are in the tree structure, so i think it should be possible to make these checks in a cleaner way ...

Answer (score 0):

I like using this pattern:

1) Add a getter function to your component class for the field you want to check:

`get openDateGroup() { return this.myFormGroup.get('openDateGroup'); }`

2) Use in template like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="openDateGroup.errors?.preOpenBeforeOpenViolation; let errorInfo">
        Pre-open date ({{errorInfo.openDate | febDate}}) may not be after open date ({{errorInfo.preOpenDate | febDate}})
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple *ngIf suffices to hide or show errors, we have custom CVA forms mixed with Angular Material and Reactive Forms in our applications, here is an example of how we wired it up:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>Text Value</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="textValue">
     <mat-error *ngIf="!isTextFormControlValid('textValue')">Please enter a valid string.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
isFormControlValid(formControlName: string): boolean {
    let foundControl: AbstractControl = this.formGroup.get(formControlName);
    if (foundControl) {
        return foundControl.valid;
    }
   return false;
}
```